# Cron daemon's status check on production server

Tags: linux, unix, scripting, cron

I have a script which need to be run as cron job.

In the staging environment i could run the script as a cronjob. but in the production environment it is not working,

so i checked whether cron daemon is running on the production

```
ps -ax|grep cron
```

but this command gives me following error message.

```
Warning: bad syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See /usr/share/doc/procps-3.2.7/FAQ
 4120 ?        Ss     0:06 crond
13640 pts/6    S+     0:00 grep cron
```

could anybody explain me what is wrong with this command

```
# housekeeper script
* * * * * sh  /product/abc/tools/housekeeper.sh -t x
```

Comment: show output from `crontab -l`

Comment: i have updated the question with the output from crontab -l

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `sh` cron runs scripts using sh anyway. Capture the output of your script to a file and see what it's saying

```
* * * * * /product/abc/tools/housekeeper.sh -t x >/tmp/file.out 2>&1
```

Also, cron emails errors to the user who is running the script so check their mail. Post any relevant information if you need further assistance.

Comment: could you tell me where can i find the cronjob log file

Comment: `>/tmp/file.out 2>&1` says to redirect the stdout ans stderr of the job to `/tmp/file.out` so look at that file.

Comment: on the staging environment i can capture the output of my script.but in the production it is not happening.... So i want to find out why script is not running. since script is not running it does not produce the file.out even. is there a log file for crontab command. if so what is the locaiton

Comment: Check /var/log - depending on distro/configuration it could be in syslog,messages,cron-* etc

Comment: i don't have root permission to view this log file. i don't understand why it is not running on production as it is on staging. i did no change to the configuration. :(

Comment: Then you need to get someone with suitable permissions to work with you - we can't help any further.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `/product/abc/tools/housekeeper.sh -t x` into bash script file like this:

```
\#!/bin/sh
/product/abc/tools/housekeeper.sh -t x
```

I know that this is ugly hack but cron sometimes have problems whith commands parameters.

After you create file add job to cron

`* * * * * /dir/to/that/scriptfile.sh`

Comment: Did you face such a problem about command parameters? I always run cron jobs with/without parameters and did not notice any problem.

Comment: Yup i had problems with php script running from cron `php -f` and that solves my problem